# Do I need two transit visas for round-trip travel through the US?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I am flying from Canada to Costa Rica, but connecting in Houston.  I am an Indian citizen so I will need to get a transit visa to be allowed into the US.  Do I need to apply for two such transit visas (second for the return flight)?  If so, do I apply for both at the same time?

Comment: This is a very good question.  I spent several minutes looking around the internet and found absolutely no information about whether a single US transit visa could be issued for multiple transits of the US (analogous to a multiple-entry tourist visa, for example).

Answer (score 9):

After much digging, I found out that the number of entries a C-1 visa can be issued for is country-specific, based on visa reciprocity.

To find whether you can get a multiple entry C-1 visa (or any other visa type) requires consulting the US visa reciprocity tables, [which tell you](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/fees/reciprocity-by-country.html):

> For temporary visitors (nonimmigrants) to the United States, the reciprocity tables available from the drop-down menu above show applicable visa issuance fees by country and by visa classification type, and the maximum period of visa validity and **number of applications, or entries, that may be authorized**.

[For India, we see](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/fees/reciprocity-by-country/IN.html) that a C-1 visa can be issued for multiple entries and a 60-month (five year) validity period. And to show that they do vary by country, see [the tables for Iran](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/fees/reciprocity-by-country/IR.html), which show that only a single entry visa good for 3 months can be issued.

And as I've noted before, you can transit on a B-1/B-2 visa, so if you have any thought of engaging in tourism in the US at some point in the future, you may wish to apply for that visa instead. The cost is the same and it is good for 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed very hard to find whether the C-1 can be used multiple times but this [document](http://photos.state.gov/libraries/turkey/461177/pdf/7t337.pdf) suggests that at least such visas exist. On the other hand, here is a C Visa [image: picture of a C Visa] which I think shows a 2 under the number of entries although it is somewhat hard to see but it's definitely neither 1 nor M. This makes me think that the C Visa  can be 1, 2, M. I would apply once showing the need for two entries.

A [US Visas](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/visa-expiration-date.html) official page says

> A visa issued for multiple entries (denoted under “entries” with a certain number (2, 3, etc.) or “M” for multiple/unlimited entries)

So such a visa in general exists.

Comment: What types of visas may be issued with which limits can be seen [here](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/fees/reciprocity-by-country.html).

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy I do not see how that page helps deciding whether C1 Visas are multiple entry. Entering a country leads to a table with the header "Number of Applications" but that's not "Number of entries".

Comment: @chx According to the State Department they mean the same thing. See my answer.

Comment: @chx, what they call "Number of Applications" here actually means how many times you can use a visa to apply for entry into the country. Despite the fact that visa stickers say "entries", the limitation is posed on the number of applications, not entries. So if you have a "single-entry" visa and upon arrival are refused entry, your visa is consumed even though you never gained that entry.

Answer (score -1):

You can get B-1/B-2 visa if you wish to make multiple entries into the United States of America. That should be all you need. You can apply two at the same time.